# PHP string concatenation

Tags: php

I have a URL 
I am passing a value through URL.

`localhost/map/2/map1.php?w1=15609`

I can test the value is being passed to my php file. So far so good. 
On my php file

```
<?php 
$id_1 = $_GET['w1'];
echo $id_1;
?>
```

My question is how can I insert the `$id_1` instead of 13085

```
downloadUrl("gen_xml1.php?w1=13085", function(data)
```

Eventually I want to create the following

```
downloadUrl("gen_xml1.php?w1="+$id_1", function(data)
```

However this is not working. Any suggestions.

Comment: Get rid of the quote after the id_1 code. Like `"gen_xml1.php?w1="+$id_1, function(data)`

Comment: @CyberFla: your code shouldn't parse, and PHP should write an error to its error log (if error logging is turned on). You should definitely check the log file for errors, because it might reveal what's wrong with the code (parse error in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if `downloadUrl` function in PHP :

```
downloadUrl("gen_xml1.php?w1=$id_1", function(data)
//or
downloadUrl("gen_xml1.php?w1=" . $id_1, function(data)
```

Or `downloadUrl` function is in JS then try this :

```
downloadUrl("gen_xml1.php?w1=<?PHP echo $id_1?>", function(data)
```

Comment: Your answered worked like magic. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the operator for concatenating strings is the dot (`.`).
So you would need to change your code to be something like this:

```
downloadUrl("gen_xml1.php?w1=" . $id_1, function(data)
```

You can read more about string operators here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php